# what analytic tool can I use for tracking exactly what users click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, analytics, web-analytics, web-analytics-tools

Please advise what tool can I use to track what user is exactly clicking i.e. click-streams – to view the actual click-stream of each visitor.

I came across "rail stat" but it seems outdated (09'). I also saw "clicky" but am unsure if I can see click streams with it?

So what other analytic tool can I use to view click streams?

Every answer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You could try the "event tracking" part of google analytics which allows you to track interactions with your site (clicks etc etc) rather than just the normal per-page.

Here is a snippet from the Event Tracking docs:

**Event Tracking Overview**

Event Tracking is a method available in the ga.js tracking code that you can use to record user interaction with website elements, such as a Flash-driven menu system. This is accomplished by attaching the method call to the particular UI element you want to track. When used this way, all user activity on such elements is calculated and displayed as Events in the Analytics reporting interface. Additionally, pageview calculations are unaffected by user activity tracked using the Event Tracking method. Finally, Event Tracking employs an object-oriented model that you can use to collect and classify different types of interaction with your web page objects.

By contrast, tracking web page objects using the urchin.js tracking code requires virtual URL creation and provides no object hierarchy. With the legacy urchin.js code, user interaction with page objects is calculated and displayed as part of total page views to your site, and no distinction is made between actual and virtual pageviews.

With ga.js, you would commonly apply Event Tracking to:

- Any Flash-driven element, like a
- Flash website, or a Flash Movie player
- Embedded AJAX page elements
- Page gadgets
- File downloads
     Load times for data

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/), which includes an option to both record a user's DOM stream for later playback and to record a heat map.

OWA is a standalone PHP app that is able to monitor multiple domains. It is under active development with version 1.5 out any day now.

HTH